# Sidekiq Client error handling

Tags: redis, sidekiq

I would like to know if there is a way to rescue redis connection errors, so that I can use a alternative datastore to push jobs. We use client side middleware to set current thread user etc, so rescuing .perform_async wouldn't be of much help. Also, Client side middleware doesn't seem to support error handling. Is there a workaround somehow that I can rescue for redis connection errors inside client middleware? The approach that I could think of was implement a heartbeat to redis, set a global flag to push jobs to an alternative datastore inside middleware. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in config/initializers/sidekiq.rb :

```
class SidekiqErrorHandler
  def call(worker_class, job, queue, redis_pool)
    begin
      Sidekiq.redis {|conn| conn.ping}
      yield
    rescue
      klass = worker_class.constantize
      klass.new.perform(*(job['args']))
      false
    end
  end
end
```

The `constantize` was unnecessary in a Rails 4 app, but I found it was needed in a Rails 5 app recently.

```
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { :size => 1 }
  config.client_middleware { |chain| chain.add SidekiqErrorHandler } unless Rails.env.test?
end
```

This is also handy (in the same file) :

```
if Rails.env.development?
  require 'sidekiq/testing'
  Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
end
```

This allows sidekiq jobs to run in-line, to allow for easy debugging locally.